# VS Code fails to open devcontainer locally but works on Codespaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

As shown below I get a weird error message when I "Reopen in Devcontainer", yet the devcontainer works on codespaces. I have no idea why. Details below:

- Reproducible example that does not open in local devcontainer: https://github.com/robinlovelace/opengeohub2023
- The [.devcontainer.json](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/opengeohub2023/blob/main/.devcontainer.json) that is causing the issue that seems fine to me:

```json
{
    "image": "ghcr.io/robinlovelace/opengeohub2023:main",
    // "forwardPorts": [3000],
    "customizations": {
        // Configure properties specific to VS Code.
        "vscode": {
            // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
            "extensions": [
                "reditorsupport.r",
                "quarto.quarto",
                "ionutvmi.path-autocomplete"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

- Codespaces working: https://codespaces.new/Robinlovelace/opengeohub2023
- See error log here: https://github.com/Robinlovelace/opengeohub2023/issues/14#issuecomment-1696953530

[image]

Comment: Update: I'm re-downloading the image with docker pull ghcr.io/robinlovelace/opengeohub2023:main

Comment: That didn't fix it. So unsure of the cause and not sure of next steps to debug this.